# How many messages on the ActiveMQ queue

Tags: activemq-classic

As part of my reporting I want to report on how many messages are still on the queue.  If my system is running correctly I should have 0 or very few messages on the queue (100 for example, definitely not 1000)

What is the nest way to get the message count, or at least to see if there are say 1000 messages still on the queue.  Would using `activemq.prefetchSize` in the header be the best way?

Answer (score 1):

Using `activemq.prefetchSize` will not tell you how many messages are on a queue. In order to determine that you'll need to use one of ActiveMQ's management interfaces, e.g.:

- [Web Console](https://activemq.apache.org/web-console)
- [JMX](https://activemq.apache.org/jmx)
- [REST interface](https://activemq.apache.org/rest) (scroll down to "Rest Management" section)

Answer (score -1):

I took a dirty way to do this by accessing the page and then parsing the html